# Arduino + HM-10/11 + ANCS to get notifications for iPhone

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I am wondering if there are any current solution to receive notifications on iPhone through ANCS and HM-10/11 Bluetooth LE module. An Arduino library?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488529/is-it-possible-to-use-hm-10-or-hm-11-ble-module-with-arduino-to-communicate-with/30625967#30625967

One of the answer of this question talked about a number of AT commands that can be used to configure the HM-10/11 to use the ANCS. But the part receiving and getting the notification details seems to be quite complicated. In addition, it should also require an iOS app to establish the connection according to the note below 1.5.

There seemed to be no information online about this even though the manufacturer confirmed with me they do provide support for ANCS for this module.

Are there anyone working on this with an Arduino? Could you please share more about this?

Or are there anyone who can help develop this library together?

Comment: I don't see anything about needing an app. Try searching for `ANCS CC2541`